# Can open website using its IP, not domain

Tags: windows-vista

My father in law can't connect to http://www.yeheytv.info. I looked up that site's IP, and using that (`76.191.104.570`), we were able to access the website. His laptop runs on windows vista. We tried all three browsers – IE, Firefox and Chrome. Same thing. The browser can only connect using the site's IP address.

What complicates matters is that he is based in italy and I am in NZ. His laptop's system language is in Italian, making it hard for me to check things using TeamViewer. I checked parental controls (translating every word in Google as I looked around), and did not find any site blocked from there. I followed [these instructions](http://www.pcworld.com/article/195868/i_cant_access_a_particular_web_site.html) and I was able to get the site's IP address and connect to it.

Except for yeheytv.info, the guy's laptop can access all other websites.

What should we do?

Comment: Can he access the site using a proxy server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the site is accessible through IP, but not the domain itself, this is probably because

- the ISP blocks the domain (unlikely)
- the DNS server your father in law is using has some hiccups

Try [changing the DNS server addresses](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-TCP-IP-settings) specified in the internet connection to either

- Google DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 or
- OpenDNS: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220

There are a couple of other free DNS services, but those are the ones used by most, I guess.